# How to use external classes into a strategy pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I implemented a strategy pattern for a poker hand history file parser (PHP or Java code). I have a problem to create a clean OOP way for classes and objects used by the several strategies.

In real life :

I have a class Game which has Hand(s)

```
class Hand
{
    ... // attributes for all strategies 
    ... // (in fact : attributes that define the "core" of a Hand)
}
class Game
{
    Hand hands[];
}
```

One strategy will create an object Game and the Hands

```
class StrategyA implements IStrategy // strategy pattern    
{
    Game game;
    function Parse()
    {
        game = new Game();
        ...
    }
}
```

And this strategy will need specific attributes for game **and each hands**
I cannot put theses attributes into Hand or Game though there only used by one strategy and not the others.
My question is : what is the best OOP way ? Create specific classes for the strategy ?

```
class HandForStrategyA extends Hand
{
    Int x; // useful only in the strategy A context
}
class StrategyA
{
    Game game;
    HandForStrategyA hands[];
}
```

It seems the obvious answer but I am still wondering if there any better ways. Furthermore, I have a problem with semantic : what kind of name should I give to my classes (HandFor... feels bad !).
I am an old-school programmer, very procedural, and I lose so much time to think about "clean" OOP !

Answer (score 1):

You answered the question yourself "And **this strategy will need specific attributes** for game and hands". You write a a strategy and the attributes are going to be part of this strategy.

Comment: Important : specific attributes for EACH hand. So, I have to create a class that inherit the Hand class, just for my strategy ? Is there other way ?

Comment: when you create a strategy, you normally pass a reference to the object that the strategy is going to act upon. so in your case Hand is passed in as a reference to the strategy...for e.g. the constructor would look something like this "public MyStrategy(Hand context)". naming is consistent with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: This means that I have to remove Hand hands from Game. I am ok with it, but is it "clean" ? A game has hands, so hands should be attribute of Game, should'n it ?

Comment: First of all I really like your enthusiasm and willing to learn new paradigm. yes hands should be part of game. so in this case, you would pass the game to the strategy. I suggest you also go through the GRASP patterns here. It provides some guidelines on what belongs where when things are not natural and obvious: http://faculty.inverhills.edu/dlevitt/CS%202000%20(FP)/GRASP%20Patterns.pdf

Comment: First of all : thank you very much for all your answers and comments (I mean it). Since I have to pass the Game to the Strategy, I am still stuck with my Hand problem :-) Do I have to create a class like HandForStrategyA ? Since this class contain only attributes, is it better to create arrays in the StrategyA class for each attribute instead of one array of HandForStrategyA ?

Comment: May be strategy is not the right thing for you. give me an example of the attributes in Hand and also example of few attributes required by the strategy that does not belong in Hand